# Writing a simple pass with LLVM

Tags: c++, makefile, llvm

I'm new to C++ and I was having some trouble getting this to work. I was trying to go through the example at http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html and I was having some trouble at the end of the section **Basic code required**, namely the part the says:

> Now that it’s all together, compile the file with a simple “gmake”
>   command in the local directory and you should get a new file
>   “Debug+Asserts/lib/Hello.so” under the top level directory of the LLVM
>   source tree (not in the local directory).

I didn't modify their source code but when I run make I get this error:

```
llvm[0]: Compiling Hello.cpp for Release+Asserts build (PIC)
In file included from Hello.cpp:15:
In file included from /Users/mtrajano/Documents/school/llvm-3.5.0.src/include/llvm/ADT/Statistic.h:29:
In file included from /Users/mtrajano/Documents/school/llvm-3.5.0.src/include/llvm/Support/Atomic.h:17:
/Users/mtrajano/Documents/school/llvm-3.5.0.src/include/llvm/Support/DataTypes.h:36:10: fatal error: 'cmath' file not found
#include <cmath>
         ^
1 error generated.
rm: /Users/mtrajano/Documents/school/llvm-3.5.0.src/lib/Transforms/Hello/Release+Asserts/Hello.d.tmp: No such file or directory
make: *** [/Users/mtrajano/Documents/school/llvm-3.5.0.src/lib/Transforms/Hello/Release+Asserts/Hello.o] Error 1
```

Can anyone direct me as to what I did wrong? If you would like any further information, I can provide it

Comment: is the rest of LLVM compiling? looks like your makefiles are somehow messed up

Comment: Yes thank you for the followup it was a stupid mistake, I added Release+Asserts/bin to the front of path variable so that I could use their executables, and for some reason that was giving it problems. I'm guessing it was using llvm's clang instead of my system's? I dont know, but When I added it to the end it worked

Answer (score 1):

Well, the header file for cmath is not visible to the compiler.  This may be helpful:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cmath

Try compiling a simple c++ program that uses cmath, that will tell you if it's installed and visible to gcc, depending on whether the example compiles and runs or not.

What I suspect is, you don't have all the prerequisite software from LLVM installed on your machine.  Try looking at the installation instructions to see if you missed something there.

Also, there are a number of similarly titled questions on Stack Overflow already which have answers -- have you read through those?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just compiled a simple c++ program in a separate directory that printed out the absolute value of a number using the cmath header and it compiled fine.

Comment: So, your next step would be to examine the installation of your LLVM software.  Sorry I can't be of more help here, but at least you've got a "next step"...  :-) best of luck.  Again I suggest reading the related questions here.